# Precision of numpy's diff()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I find that `numpy.diff` gives an inaccurate result, which can be shown by the following code snippet.

```
import numpy as np

# test data
arr_a = np.linspace(10**8,10**9,500,dtype=np.double)
arr_b = np.linspace(10**9,10**10,500,dtype=np.double)
arr_c = np.linspace(10**10,10**11,500,dtype=np.double)

# results
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

plt.plot( np.diff(arr_c,n=2), "r", linewidth=1.0,label=r"arr_c")
plt.plot( np.diff(arr_b,n=2), "g", linewidth=2.0,label=r"arr_b" )
plt.plot( np.diff(arr_a,n=2), "b", linewidth=2.0,label=r"arr_a" )
plt.legend()
```

The output is shown below
[image]
From this figure, we see that `np.diff(arr_b,n=2)` and `np.diff(arr_c,n=2)` are very noisy, which is far from the theoretical value (i.e., zero). Why does this happen?

Comment: If you want higher precision you should use mpmath module.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Can you show me a simple example?

Comment: [check the documentation](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/differentiation.html)

Comment: The min/max values of `np.diff(arr_b,2)` are +- 3.81e-6.  Divide by 10**9 we get values 3.e-15.  For doubles that is virtually 0.  `arr_b[1]` is `1018036072.1442885`.  If we generated 501 values (instead of 500), `b[1]` displays as `1018000000.0`, and the min/max diffs are `0`.  So the noise is mostly due to how `linspace` creates 500 numbers - that combined with the limited precision of float point values.

Comment: Look at a smaller `arr_b = np.linspace(0,10,10)` and its diff.  Looking at the raw numbers should tell you more than a plot of 500.